# Create Kivy package for Windows from OSX

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, kivy

I've packaged a Kivy program that I made on OSX, but I also want to be able to distribute it for Windows and Linux. Is there currently a way of creating a Windows or Linux package from OSX? Or is there an ETA on when Buildozer will be able to create Windows packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will be to setup a VM for Windows and a VM for Linux, then create the packages for each OS within those VMs.

You might be able to use pyinstaller with Wine to make the Windows package directly on OSX - I have read that this can be done on Linux, so in theory it could work on OSX. But you will probably get better results using a VM where you can also test the package and make sure it installs and runs properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's about what I expected. I've got VMware, and product codes for Windows 7 and 8, but finding a legitimate .iso has been troublesome.

Comment: If you have valid keys, you could try [Microsoft Software Recovery](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery).

Comment: Yeah, funny thing about Microsoft Software Recovery process is that I gave it a code that I got from a download of Windows 8, but I got "We encountered a problem with the product key you provided.  Please visit the  Microsoft Support Contact Us page for assistance.  Refer to Message Code 715-123130" I tried other codes, but it didn't matter what code I gave it, I got the same error message every time.